# Show multiple proportions in Geom Bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

I want to show the proportion of **sick** and **normal** Gender(**M/F**) in different **AgeGroup** in the same Bar Graph. Suppose if you see below graph, I have total **77949** people in **18-25 years AgeGroup**. Within the same bar: **18-25 Years**, I also want to show the proportion in percentage of **sick** and **normal** **Gender(M/F)**. The code for below mentioned graph is mentioned. Furthermore, I am also showing some dummy data and the required graph below.

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = people, aes(x = AgeGroup)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = sex)) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% group_by(sex, AgeGroup) %>% 
              summarize(n = n()) %>% group_by(AgeGroup) %>%
              summarize(sex = sex, n = n, perc = n / sum(n)),
              aes(y = n, label = paste(scales::comma(n), 
                                       scales::percent(perc, 0.1), 
                                       sep = '\n'), group = Gender), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = scales::comma(after_stat(count))),
            nudge_y = 10000, fontface = 2) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0),
        axis.text.y.left = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y.left = element_blank())
```

**Required Graph Example for all Age Groups**

[image]

**Dummy Data Frame**. In below table, **1= Normal**, and  **condition> 1 = sick**.

| ID | Condition | Gender | Age | Age Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | M | 32 | 26-35 years |
| 2 | 4 | F | 63 | 56-65 years |
| 3 | 7 | M | 43 | 36-45 years |
| 4 | 1 | F | 32 | 26-35 years |
| 5 | 3 | F | 65 | 56-65 years |
| 6 | 2 | M | 80 | 76-80 years |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would suggest to create a summary dataset outside of ggplot (which you basically do anyway inside `geom_text`). The rest is to set the right `group` aes which in your case involves the interaction by `Gender` and `Condition`.

As your data was a bit sparse I created some fake random example data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

n <- 1000

people <- data.frame(
  Condition = sample(c(1:4, 7), n, replace = TRUE),
  Gender = sample(c("M", "F"), n, replace = TRUE),
  AgeGroup = sample(c(
    "26-35 years", "36-45 years",
    "56-65 years", "76-80 years"
  ), n, replace = TRUE)
)

people_sum <- people |> 
  mutate(sick = if_else(Condition > 1, "Sick", "Normal")) |> 
  count(AgeGroup, Gender, sick) |> 
  group_by(AgeGroup) |> 
  mutate(perc = n / sum(n)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(label = paste(
    paste(sick, Gender), 
    scales::comma(n),
    scales::percent(perc, 0.1),
    sep = "\n"
  ))

ggplot(data = people_sum, aes(x = AgeGroup, y = n)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Gender, group = interaction(sick, Gender)), color = "black") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = label, group = interaction(sick, Gender)),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
    lineheight = 1, size = 8 / .pt
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = after_stat(scales::comma(y)), group = AgeGroup), 
    fontface = 2, stat = "summary", fun = "sum", nudge_y = 1, vjust = 0
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0),
    axis.text.y.left = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y.left = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works but its bit messy in terms of too much information involved in a single bar and not readable. I guess, increasing the size of bars will do the job, but not sure how to do that !